# Suggestion on how to consolidate VMWare VM snapshots

Tags: vmware, esxi, snapshot

I was given a copy of a VM with many snapshots.  The size of the folder that contains the VM is about 200GB and there is about 371 snapshots in it.

`ls | grep [.]vmdk | wc
 372       372     14513`

I am not sure if the VM is created using VMWare Workstation Player or using an ESXI server.  I copied the whole folder with the VM and snapshots onto my ESXI 6.7 server and then try to register the VM but my ESXI server just refuse to do it, the web client simply crashed and then reload itself so I was landed back to the ESXI web login page.

My question is, is there a way to consolidate all the snapshots back into a single vmdk via command line?  I am hoping that if I do that then I can load the VM register the VM in my ESXI server.

Thanks

Comment: You exceeded the number of snapshots, so you will have to consolidate them via the command line, until you reach the supported number.  You have to determine where the VM came from, how you solve this, will depend on those facts.  If it came from VMWare Workstation you have to export the VM.

Comment: Or you can use the *vmware-vdiskmanager* command line utility to clone a new, single .vmdk file. (If you can identify which of the many .vmdk snapshots is the most recent.) That utility is included with Workstation, but I believe it's also available as part of the VDDK for vSphere 6.7 (https://code.vmware.com/web/sdk/67/vddk) and earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for answering my questions.  I think I resolved the issue already.  Originally I thought there were many snapshots but apparently the hard disk of the VM is created using the Workstation Player's option "Split virtual disk into multiple files" so that's why I see so many *.vmdk files in the VM directory.  It does have snapshots but not as many as I originally thought.

Anyhow, the process was kind of tedious and time consuming but I think it does what I needed to do.

1. I uploaded the whole VM directory into my ESXI server
2. Instead of using the Web UI to register the VM, I did it manually via SSH. 
   The command I used is `vim-cmd solo/registervm
   /vmfs/volumes/5ad63960-9e683519-7280-000e0cc162f3/VMs/Some_Random_VM.vmx`
3. I then use the ESXI Web UI, Virtual Machines -> Some_Random_VM ->
   Manage snapshots -> Delete snapshot.  The Delete snapshot option would
   consolidate the snapshot back to the base image.
4. I attempted to start the VM at that point but it wouldn't let me, I guess that's because the VM was created in VMWare Workstation Player.  I unregister the VM and then copied the whole VM directory back to my desktop
5. I use the "VMWare vCenter Converter Standalone Client" which convert the VM to be ESXI compatible and uploaded it to my ESXI server
6. Viola!  I can start my VM thru the ESXI Web UI now

There's couple round trips that I have to do to get what I need and I am pretty sure there's probably a much easier way but at the end, I get what I wanted.

Perhaps that's the disadvantage of using VMWare free version of their products, all the convenient utilities are not included.